# corrently printing strange characters

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, decode

For the life of me, I cant figure out what I am doing wrong

```
import urllib
import csv

with open("mydb.txt", 'rb') as f:
    readr = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",", quotechar="'")
    for row in readr:
        mylist = []
        for i in row:
            code=urllib.unquote(i)
            mylist.append(code)
        print mylist
```

the problem is I keep getting things like:

```
['S\xc3\xa3o Desid\xc3\xa9rio', 'BA', 'Convencional', '1759', '-12.52332', '-45.59509']
```

What is this `'S\xc3\xa3o Desid\xc3\xa9rio'` ? it should be São Desidário. How can I fix it?

Comment: You are printing the *list object*, which shows string representations. These representations are for UTF-8 encoded byte strings and are entirely correct.

Comment: And how do I decode it?

Comment: @relima I have shown how to decode it in my answer, it's not too difficult.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: you are right! I was printing a list object.. and that was my mistake. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are printing the list object instead of its members. Trying using `str.join` to format the list to your liking.
2. You should consider the "unicode sandwich" approach ("bytes on the outside, unicode on the inside"). Convert all of your input to `unicode` immediately upon input, and convert it to encoded bytes on output.

This program might suit you:

```
import urllib
import csv

with open("mydb.txt", 'rb') as f:
    readr = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",", quotechar="'")
    for row in readr:
        mylist = []
        for i in row:
            i = i.decode('utf-8')
            code=urllib.unquote(i)
            mylist.append(code)
            print type(code),code
        print u','.join(mylist).encode('utf-8')
```